# Как выполнить расположение абзацев в форме шестиугольника на странице?

Tags: html, вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка, less

Имеется следующий код:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fira+Sans:300,400,700" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>Gezatone</title>
</head>
<body>
  <main>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="main-gezatone__revolution">
                    <h2>Революция в омоложении лица!<br>
                        Первый аппарат для RF-лифтинга в домашних условиях<br>
                        <span>Gezatone V-Line!</span></h2>
                    <div class="main-gezatone__revolution__content">
                        <div class="main-gezatone__revolution__content__left">
                            <div class="main-gezatone__revolution__content__left__elem"><p>Восстанавливает<br>овал лица</p></div>
                            <div class="main-gezatone__revolution__content__left__elem"><p>Разглаживает<br>морщины</p></div>
                            <div class="main-gezatone__revolution__content__left__elem"><p>Подтягивает<br>обвисшую кожу</p></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="main-gezatone__revolution__content__right">
                            <div class="main-gezatone__revolution__content__right__elem"><p>Выравнивает<br>носогубные складки</p></div>
                            <div class="main-gezatone__revolution__content__right__elem"><p>Корректирует<br>второй подбородок</p></div>
                            <div class="main-gezatone__revolution__content__right__elem"><p>Повышает<br>выработку коллагена</p></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="main-gezatone__revolution__content-mob">
                        <div class="main-gezatone__revolution__content-mob__left">
                            <p>Восстанавливает<br>
                                овал лица</p>
                            <p>Разглаживает<br>
                                морщины</p>
                            <p>Подтягивает<br>
                                обвисшую кожу</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="main-gezatone__revolution__content-mob__right">
                            <p>Выравнивает<br>
                                носогубные складки</p>
                            <p>Корректирует<br>
                                второй подбородок</p>
                            <p>Повышает<br>
                                выработку коллагена</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
    </div>
  </main>
</body>
</html>
```

Необходимо расположить элементы `p` из блока `.main-gezatone__revolution__content` в форме шестиугольника, как на скриншотах:
http://joxi.ru/KAxlbzXCMW11zA - десктоп
http://joxi.ru/Vm6B9QzHDBjjPm - планшет
Кроме того, на мобильных абзацы должны выглядеть так - http://joxi.ru/Grq7vLKfQ1kz92, но с этим особых трудностей не возникло.

Попытался пойти через flex, на десктопе выглядит более-менее нормально, но на планшетных разрешениях не смотрится. Как правильно выполнить верстку абзацев, как на скриншотах?

Полный код находится здесь: https://codepen.io/sasha_jarvi/pen/NoBaZM

Comment: сделать 3 строки, 2 колонки. верхний и нижний выровнять к центру, средний наоборот к краям. А в мобильной просто по центру все

Comment: В принципе, примерно так и сделал (результат см. ниже)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Реализовал сетку таким образом с использованием Grid:

```
&__content {
        width: 85%;
        margin: @margin-base;
        background: url(https://i.postimg.cc/T1QJ2Snz/young-woman-touch.png) no-repeat center;
        display: grid;
        grid-template-rows: repeat(2, auto);

        @media screen and (max-width: 980px) {
          grid-template-rows: auto;
          grid-template-columns: repeat(3, auto);
          justify-content: space-between;
          margin-bottom: 50px;
        }
}
```

Полный код см. здесь: https://codepen.io/sasha_jarvi/pen/NoBaZM